# PHP - Get information about image (Height and Width) without loading it

Tags: php, image, height, width

Is it possible to get image information without loading the actual image with PHP? In my case I want the Height and Width.

I have this code to fetch images from a directory. I echo out the image's url and fetch it with JS.

```
<?php

    $directory = "./images/photos/";
    $sub_dirs = glob($directory . "*");
    $i = 0;
    $len = count($sub_dirs);
    foreach($sub_dirs as $sub_dir)
    {
        $images = glob($sub_dir . '/*.jpg');
        $j = 0;
        $len_b = count($images);
        foreach ($images as $image) 
        {

            if ($j == $len_b - 1) {
                echo $image;
            } else {
                echo $image . "|";
            }

            $j++;

        }

        if ($i == $len - 1) {
        } else {
            echo "|";
        }
        $i++;
    }

?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: You have to use the image in one way or another if you want the information, you could, however, store the information in a text tile of something like that to access it later on.

Comment: @Philip PHP is going to parse every image you pass to it, but Cal's answer is right due to the fact that when the function gets the sizes and assigns them to the variables it will free the memory. If I ware you I should stick with his method.

Comment: @Jonast92 - Your answer/comment is the way I will do this. Thanks.

Comment: Alright, @Philip, I created an answer with the same comment/answer, since I guess it counts as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getImageSize()` is the proper way to get this information in PHP

It does a minimal amount of work based on the type of image. For example, a GIF image's height/width are stored in a header. Very easy to access and read. So this is how the function most likely gets that information from the file. For a JPEG, it has to do a little more work, using the SOFn markers.

The fastest way to access this information would be to maintain a database of file dimensions every time a new one is uploaded.

Given your current situation. I recommend writing a PHP script that takes all of your current image files, gets the size with this function, and then inserts the info into a database for future use.

Answer (score 6):

It depends what you mean by "without loading it".

The built-in [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) does this.

```
list($w, $h) = getimagesize($filename);
```

Comment: I have thousands of images and if I had to load it, it would take ages before I retrieved the info about the image.

Comment: What do you mean by "load"? You have to (obviously) look at the bytes of the image to find out its size. Are you talking about caching the sizes in a file or database? Your question is very vague.

Comment: I'm not interested in its "size", I'm only interested in its width and height. I'm talking about catching the sizes in a file. Jpeg to be exact.

Comment: And what I mean with load is that on every request it shouldn't "download" the pictures to retrieve it's height and width...

Comment: Your question still does not make sense. You **cannot** find out the height and width of an image without reading some of the bytes in that image's file.

Comment: My question was, is it possible? What is so hard to understand with that. You have actually answered that q with the latest comment, try to leave out the arrogance next time.

Comment: Your question was honestly "Can I get the width and height of an image without knowing anything about the file"? That's the same as me asking you what color socks I'm wearing (but you're not allowed to look).

Comment: At least with getImageSize(), he can just take a peek at your feet instead of looking over your entire body to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can programmatically get the image and check the dimensions using Javascript...

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
```

This can be useful if the image is not a part of the markup ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can store the width'n'height information in a text file, and load it later on.

Answer (score 2):

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES["Artwork"]['tmp_name']);
```

Use this.